# UI Text View in Segmented Control - Change Color of Text

Tags: ios, uitextview, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I change the color and size of text which is used in the segmented control using uitextView where textView is the outlet

Here is .h file

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>

{

IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * control;
IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

}

-(IBAction)switchcontrol:(id)sender;
```

This is .m file code

```
 -(IBAction)switchcontrol:(id)sender {

if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {



    [textView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [textView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [textView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    textView.text = @"This is text 1";

}



if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

    [textView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [textView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [textView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    textView.text = @"This is text 2";

}
}
```